# Swift: Testing async functions nested in timers?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, asynchronous

I'm new to swift, and facing an issue with testing asynchronous swift code nested within a timer.

I have a swift `.scheduledTimer` that sends data to an API every 5 minutes in swift via `URLSession.shared.upload`

In order for the asynchronous call to work within .scheduledTimer I've wrapped it in `Task` , like so:

```
self.timerProvider.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeBetweenAPISendsInSeconds, repeats: true) { _ in
    Task {
        await URLSession.shared.upload(for: request, from: encodedSessionBatch)
    }
}
```

The problem I have is with unit testing. Specifically:

```
func test_scheduledTimer_sendsSessionBatchToAPI() async throws {
    MockTimer.currentTimer.fire()
    XCTAssertEqual(mockApiDispatcher.sentToAPICount, 1)
}
```

That "sentToAPICount" won't get picked up, because the test fires before the async operation completes. This normally isn't a problem with async tests, I either:

- Stick 'async/await' in the test function. Can't do that in this instance(?), because the async call is nested within a timer
- Use expectation.fulfill()...which I'm guessing requires a callback to use effectively, which this code doesn't have?

As mentioned, I'm relatively new to swift, and eager for ideas: what's the standard way of asynchronous tests nested in timers?

Comment: You’re already part way there by using dependency injection to mock out your `timerProvider`. I think you can just apply the same idea one more time to extract a `DataUpdater` interface (example naming, idk what your actual networking code does). You can then provide a mock instance that contains an expectation, and fulfills that expectation when the `upload()` method is called. You can then wait for that expectation to assert that it was called. This’ll have the added benefit of then allowing you to test your networking code separately, independently of any timing concerns

Comment: Hi @Alexander - thanks for the response. I simplified above for example's sake, but in my actual code URLSession .shared.upload is mocked out. The issue is that the .upload method is async, which means the mocked value needs to be async too. So even if I'm calling a mock .upload, it fails to fire in time.

Comment: Even if it's async, can't you wait on the expectation for a timeout? It should be near instant, so even like a 1 second timeout should surely catch it every time

Comment: Thanks @Alexander...as suggested, I ended up going with a delay. The purist side of me prefers to avoid that approach, but I wanted to move on to other challenges :)

Comment: If you wait on expectations with a timeout, you’re not actually introducing a delay, you’re just letting the run loop spin a few more times until your almost-immediately-executed async work finishes. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, it seems like you are mixing structured concurrency with older callback-based approaches. This introduces some subtle issues in your approaches:

- You are not waiting for the upload to complete before starting the next timer count which may introduce data race in the event where one upload call takes longer.

Your code will become much easier to read, test and maintain if you decide to use the scheduling mechanism provided in the new structured concurrency with [Task.sleep](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(nanoseconds:)). You can create a simple method that handles scheduling:

```swift
func scheduleUpload(after seconds: UInt64) async throws {
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: seconds * 1_000_000_000)
    try await URLSession.shared.upload(for: request, from: encodedSessionBatch)
    self.task = Task {
        try await self.scheduleUpload(after: seconds)
    }
}
```

For the initial invocation, you can just invoke the 3rd line in the method separately:

```swift
self.task = Task {
    try await self.scheduleUpload(after: seconds)
}
```

Note that here the scheduling activity is stored as a task and you can cancel this at any time by invoking [`cancel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/cancel()) on `self.task`.

Now to test this, you have to use mock scheduling mechanism instead of [Task.sleep](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(nanoseconds:)) and run your assertions.